Intersect object and interface in TypeScript
Let's say there is an object:
A = {
    id: 123,
    name: "sample",
    foo: "test1",
    bar: "test2"
}

And an interface:
interface I {
     id: number;
     name: string;
}

I need to write a function that would "filter" the object A with an interface I and get new object equals to:
{
    id: 123,
    name: "sample",
}

Any TypeScript features like keyof didn't work. Is there any way to solve this problem, preferably without using classes?

Note the last example is basically what your code already gets when accessing A via I.

Interfaces are purely a compile-time construct in TypeScript. You can't use them to direct runtime behavior.
That is to say, if the object is asserted to be constant, you could derive a new type that meets your requirements, e.g. by using a mapped type:
const A = {
    id: 123,
    name: "sample",
    foo: "test1",
    bar: "test2"
} as const;

interface I {
     id: number;
     name: string;
}

type T = {
    [K in keyof I]: (typeof A)[K]
}

// type T = {
//     id: 123;
//     name: "sample";
// }

But your requirement to filter an object at runtime based on the interface cannot be satisfied.
